# No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picke

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am implementing image_picker in my app. That is not showing any warning or message but when I run it in Android simulator it shows me an error in console:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)
E/flutter ( 5074): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:7)
E/flutter ( 5074): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5074): #1      ImagePicker.pickImage (package:image_picker/image_picker.dart:53:40)
E/flutter ( 5074): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Did you try hot reloading?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I solved my problem by simply run following command:

```
flutter clean
```

After this my Android simulator start working correctly.

Comment: After this  run : ```flutter pub get ```

Answer (score 16):

When you add a new dependency and you get this error, you should stop the app and run it again from cold. Hot restart will not work.

Answer (score 12):

First, make sure you clean your flutter project

```
flutter clean
```

then in Android studio,
**File > Invalidate and caches restart**

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 7):

Just uninstall app from your simulator and clean project by `flutter clean` and then `flutter run`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue

For anyone who happens to stumble accros this... Just Stop the app, and run it again

just a simple "turn it off and on again!"

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same issue but none of the answers mentioned above help with this problem after digging in, I find out that the minSdkVersion required for the library for android is above 19 so GO to 
**android-> app-> build.gradle** change the minSdkVersion to 19 and run app from cold start.

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "you package name"
        minSdkVersion 19   // <--here is the changes 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who still having problems on Android, 
this one solved mine..

**For some reason image_picker plugin haven't been registered automacally**

Go to Android > app > main > java> io> flutter > plugins and edit GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

1. `import io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin;`
2. paste this line inside method registerWith `ImagePickerPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin"));`

Comment: Went though all the solutions, this one seemed to be the one standing out as some out of the box solution, also went tried out @daljit-singh 's solution below but it too didnt work. Is there another way around it?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you add a dependency to pubsec yaml file and hot-refresh the app. You should re-build / re-run the app then it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

After removing the `flutter_facebook_auth` package, running `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and running the application, it will work properly

Answer (score 1):

Since the latest update the static method pickImage is not available for some reasons.
You will have to call methd getImage(source: ImageSource) for that purpose

```
    ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
final imageFile = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

Answer (score 1):

Android #

API < 29

No configuration required - the plugin should work out of the box.

API 29+

Add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" as an attribute to the  tag in AndroidManifest.xml. The attribute is false by default on apps targeting Android Q.

After that :

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

And here you go coding again...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using flutter_facebook_auth you must configure it as shown in the documentation (https://facebook.meedu.app/#/android), otherwise, image_picker will not work correctly

[Taken from the flutter_facebook_auth documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFIcQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem just When you add a new dependency and you get this error, you should stop the app and run it again.Hot restart will not work.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me is to stop and relaunch, even the clean flutter and pub get then play didn't work, you must force stop the app. thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you give uses-permission in your AndroidManifest.xml
`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and after that run

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you picking an image from camera or gallery? if you want to pick an image from the camera you need to use a real device, simulation gives error sometimes, make sure you are giving the source:

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

import 'dart:async';

flutter clean

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the image_picker version: image_picker: ^0.6.0+9

Answer (score 0):

Already follow all the responses but still not solve in my case. Still throwing "No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker"

Comment: Latest version facing this type of issue. Android working fine. But In iOS facing this issue. Did you find any solution for this?.

Comment: I faced those issues on Android after Upgrading Flutter Version. The solution I tried is downgrading the Flutter and yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
My solution was to remove another plugin: `flutter-facebook-auth`.

also, I found it here: [github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72898](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72898)

Really informative comment:

> Anyway, that's really bad situation when some plugin that is not used in the part of code crashes the app, and debug tells you that issues is with another one plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Simply stop your project and Run. It will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my app and the error was gone. I will recommend you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **flutter clean was not worked** for my app.

I solved my problem by Uninstalling my app from emulator/device and then rebuild my app and the error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

it is simple to fix. terminate the process  and then restart. to terminate on vscode : open terminal on vscode and press " ctr + c" then press "y" and press "enter" .now restart your project .hope it will work. check it and comment me if it does not work.

Answer (score -2):

Updating the dependency solve my error.

Answer (score -2):

I **resolved** the problem by **uninstalling** the app and running it **again** from *Visual Studio Cod*e.